# How do I send an email with a SSL certificate?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, smtp

I'am having some troubles sending emails with SSL certificate.
I know that there are third parties that I can use, but for reasons I don't want to discuss I can't use these.

Currently I'm using

```
System.Net.Sockets
```

to send emails. As I understand there is no way of sending emails over SSL with this method. So I came accross the

```
System.Net.Security.SslStream
```

and I found some sample code to demonstrate how to do this.

After STARTTLS command I'm creating an SslStream. This works, but when I do the handshake I get the error message: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

Here is the code where i create the SSLStream and do the handshake.

```
private SslStream _sslStream = null;
private NetworkStream _networkStream = null;
private TcpClient _client = null;
private bool _SSLActive = false;

public SmtpConnectorWithSSL(string smtpServerAddress, int port) : base(smtpServerAddress, port)
        {
            _client = new TcpClient(smtpServerAddress, port);
            _networkStream = _client.GetStream();
        }    

public override void CreateSSLConnection()
        {
            _sslStream = new SslStream(
                _networkStream,
                true,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                null
                );

            // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
            try
            {
                _sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SmtpServerAddress, GetX509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Tls, false);

                _SSLActive = true;
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                _sslStream = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                _client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _sslStream = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                _client.Close();
            }
        }
```

The error happens at the function "AuthenticateAsClient()".

Maybe it has something to do with the certificate that I'm loading?

```
public static X509CertificateCollection GetX509CertificateCollection()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\leo\OneDrive - Cumulo9 Limited\Documents\Cumulo9\StartCom\mailprimer.com\IISServer\2_mailprimer.com.crt");
        X509CertificateCollection collection1 = new X509CertificateCollection();
        collection1.Add(certificate1);
        return collection1;
    }
```

Maybe the certificate is wrong, but I don't know how to find this out. I would expect the error message to be different then.

If it's easier I can supply the whole sample project to you to if this helps.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"After STARTTLS command I'm creating an SslStream."* - after you've send the STARTTLS command or after you've got the successful response to the command?

Comment: Sorry I should say after I get the response "220 Ready to start TLS".

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was that the recipients server had a timeout of 1 second. The handshake lasted longer then 1 second and therefor the exception was thrown. After the recipients email server changed the timeout to 30 seconds the handshake was successful.